# (nginx) - Can't make OwnCloud work after restore (no images, style etc)

Tags: nginx, debian-wheezy, owncloud

I've migrated my rig from Arch Linux to Debian stable and I've restored my old OC installation but now everything seems to be blown up. (see attachments)
The desktop clients work flawlessly though. I've already checked the permissions of my owncloud dir and they seem to be fine.

Here you can see what happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/poI9p.jpg

---

```
Environment: Debian 7.6.0
Server: nginx 1.2.1
Database: MySQL
OC-Version: 7.0.2
PHP-Version: 5.4.4
```

---

**nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  8;
error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


# PORT 80 REDIRECT (TO HTTPS) YOLO

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name $DOMAIN;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
       listen 443;
       server_name $DOMAIN;
       root /usr/share/webapps/owncloud;


        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server-http.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server-http.key;
       if ($http_host != "$DOMAIN") {
                 rewrite ^ $DOMAIN$request_uri permanent;
       }

       index index.php index.html;

       location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
       location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }

        client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size

        rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;


   rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/apps/calendar/caldav.php /remote.php/caldav/ last;
        rewrite ^/apps/contacts/carddav.php /remote.php/carddav/ last;
        rewrite ^/apps/([^/]*)/(.*\.(css|php))$ /index.php?app=$1&getfile=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/remote/(.*) /remote.php last;

    error_page 403 = /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 = /core/templates/404.php;

    location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
                    deny all;
    }

    location / {
                    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
                    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

                    rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
                    rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

                    rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
                    try_files $1 =404;
                    include fastcgi.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
                    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
                    expires 30d;
                    access_log off;
    }
}
}
```

---

Thank you all!

Comment: Do the obvious: Check your logs. And sorry you had to switch to Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following this [guide](http://computermen.linuxeverywhere.org/2014/02/11/owncloud-debian-wheezy-derivates-ubuntu-using-nginx/). :-D Thanks everyone!